# Which points in the x-y plane can you write x and y as functions of u and v

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $u=x^2-y^2$ and $v=2xy$. For which points in the $(x,y)$-plane, does there exist a neighborhood in which we can write $x$ and $y$ in as functions of $u$ and $v$?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Apply the inverse function theorem: there is a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ on which $f: (x,y) \mapsto (u(x,y), v(x,y))$ is invertible iff the Jacobian at that point is invertible, so compute its determinant:
$$\det J_{(x,y)} = (2x)(2x)-(-2y)(2y) = 4(x^2+y^2)$$
This is not zero away from the origin.